# Remove someone else's website URL (which contains forward slashes) via .htaccess on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I've searched high and low for a solution to this and everything I've tried has failed. I was looking through our server logs and noticed a number of 404s where a URL has had a variable added to the end of it (for reasons we're still trying to understand).

A URL which should read:

www.example.com/property1/property2/

Instead reads:

www.example.com/property1/property2/http:/www.anothersite.com/ (notice the single slash after 'http:')

I tried using both:

`RewriteRule ^/http:/www.anothersite.com/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]` and `RewriteRule ^/http:/$ /`but to no avail. The added complication is that the site is WordPress, so I've been placing new code on the line after `RewriteBase /` of this code (standard to WP):

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any assistance much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/http:.*$ $1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Assuming you want `www.example.com/property1/property2/http:/www.anothersite.com/` to be redirected to `www.example.com/property1/property2`. Use the following to end the url with `/`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)http:.*$ $1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, strangely neither seem to be working right now - it doesn't change the URL at all. I'll have a play to see whether WordPress is causing the issues.

Comment: @Stephen, add `[R=301,NC,QSA,L]` instead. I assumed you don't want an external redirect.

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you - I can sleep now! :)

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for your kind words. Glad to be of help.

Comment: +1 for good solution. Before your edit I started writing my comment that most likely OP needs an external redirect but got pulled into a conf call.

Comment: @anubhava Wow, conf call at 1 AM. That's some dedication. I thought today was our Independence Day. :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: lol :) Yes it was indeed `Independence Day` but I have my team in US east coast and I spend time with them.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed errors like this when a mistake has been made on a webpage that I am hosting that uses a script to redirect to a specific url.  The error is that the url that I am offering is invalid. Instead of "http://example.com/filename.php" it is "http:/example.com/filename.php", which leads to it not being recognized as a url and is concatenated to the base url of the webpage.  Bottom line, you need to backtrack to the referring page that has the url embedded and correct the problem that makes that url not recognized as a url.  So it's not a problem to be handled by rewritting at all because that would only treat the symptom, not the true problem.  More clearly, the mistake in your example above is that the expected "http://" is "http:/" so it is not recogized as a URL and you need to fix that on the referring page.

Comment: You're correct about the redirection scripts but OP mentioned that they aren't aware why this is happening. I doubt that OP wouldn't know about a redirection plug-in on his WordPress install.